# How do I move a private Mercurial repository to a central server?

Tags: mercurial, repository, bitbucket, hgrc

I’m just getting started with Mercurial, and I’ve read Joel Spolsky’s [Hg Init tutorial](http://hginit.com/index.html), which I liked.

I’m wondering: let’s say I have a private repository and I work on it for about a month.  Then I decide I want to centralize it or make it public, like on [bitbucket.org](http://bitbucket.org).  I want to retain all the history.

The intuitive thing would be to use [hg clone](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#clone), but according to the docs:

> The location of the source is added to
>   the new repository's .hg/hgrc file, as
>   the default to be used for future
>   pulls.

I don’t think this is what I’d want, since the source is my local, private repository, and the destination is the public server.  I don’t want the public server trying to pull from my private repository in the future thinking *it’s* the central one.  I hope this makes sense.

Do I have to tweak the .hg/hgrc file on the server manually?  Am I approaching this correctly?

Comment: Ned had your answer, but FWIW you can use clone to create a new repository elsewhere if your destination is a ssh:// URL.  If you're talking to the server over http:// then you need to 'hg init' on the server and then 'hg push' from local.  The setting of the source as the default for pulls is mostly irrelevant on a push-clone since you'll probably never 'pull' on that remote repo -- only push to it.  If you do find yourself pulling on the remote repo man 'you can change the defaults in the [paths] section of the .hgrc.

Comment: Excellent points - thanks, Ry4an.  I see what you mean about the irrelevance of the default pull location on the server.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[BitBucket's help](http://bitbucket.org/help/UsingBitbucket#importing-existing-files-already-in-mercurial) says it's as easy as making an empty repo on BitBucket, then pushing to it:

> ... create a new empty repository via the "Create repository" page. We will assume that this repository is named blonk and is to be found on http://bitbucket.org/jespern/blonk.
>
> Now, just push to it:
>
> ```
>   $ cd ~/Work/blonk # our existing hg repository
>   $ hg push http://bitbucket.org/jespern/blonk
>   ...
> ```
>
> Done!
>
> You can edit .hg/hgrc in your repository to include the default path to Bitbucket:
>
> ```
>   $ cat .hg/hgrc
>   [paths]
>   default = http://bitbucket.org/jespern/blonk
> ```
>
> Now you can simply enter hg push and hg pull without having to specify the full URL.

Answer (score 4):

Doing this operation using 'hg push', as described, is probably the best way to do this, overall.

However in other circumstances it might be convenient, or reassuring, to note that *all* of the Hg state is contained within the .hg directory, and so simply moving this directory is enough to move the repository.

For example, if you have ssh access to a machine at example.com, you can tar (or zip) up your .hg directory in the 'private' repository, unpack it in, say, `~/repo/foo` on the remote machine (thus creating a directory `~/repo/foo/.hg` there), and then simply clone this:

```
$ hg clone ssh://example.com/repo/foo
```

This does have a slight back-door feel to it, I agree.  However, there's nothing really under-the-hood happening here, and no editing of configuration files is necessary.  When I do this, I find it less confusing than the 'proper' way.