# How to create repository on BitBucket remotely?

Tags: mercurial

I want to create a repository from my local machine using hg commands on Bitbucket instead of creating a repo manually on Bitbucket. Is it possible?

Comment: This Bitbucket documentation page  explains how to create a new repository remotely via http: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/repository-resource-423626331.html#repositoryResource-POSTanewrepository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the only way to make a BitBucket repo is on BitBucket, either through their web interface, or their API.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105427/how-do-i-move-a-private-mercurial-repository-to-a-central-server/3105582#3105582) has details of how to create an empty repo on BitBucket then push local content to it.

Answer (score 8):

I did the following using the REST API through curl command:

```
$>curl -k -X POST --user user:pass \
"https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories" -d "name=project_name"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a bitbucket repository using their API. I use [this Python script](https://bitbucket.org/jaraco/jaraco.develop/src/819da4c3e702/jaraco/develop/bitbucket.py) to create my repositories, then edit the .hgrc, then push the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using following code to create repo on Bitbacket remotely from terminal:

```
curl -u 'USERNAME' https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories -d '{"name":"REPO"}'
```

where

USERNAME - your username on BitBucket

REPO - name of repository